# splitting user's input with read command

Tags: command-line, echo

```
echo -n "# WHICH DAYS? #"
read day
```

assume user's input are: `100` `101` with one space between numbers. For example I need to extract first and second column value of day separately, which command gives this value? I tried below commands but they give whole array;

```
first_column_of_day=${day[${1}]}
echo "$first_column_of_day"

second_column_of_day=${day[${2}]}
echo "$second_column_of_day"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should tell `read` to use an array. From `help read`:

```
-a array    assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
            variable ARRAY, starting at zero
```

So, do:

```
read -a day
```

Then, use just `1` and `2`, without the `${...}`. In this case, as the help text notes, start from `0`:

```
first_column_of_day="${day[0]}"
second_column_of_day="${day[1]}"
```

`${1}` is the first argument to the script, which may or may not be `1`.

Also note that `bash`'s `read` can print a prompt:

```
-p prompt   output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
            attempting to read
```

So:

```
read -p "# WHICH DAYS? #" -a day
```